# Content not aligning to the center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Im trying to get my "Jumbotron" centered at the top and beneath it have my picture to the left and carousel on the right.

Why does all my content float to the left? Im trying to get everything centered but cant quite make it work.

Im using Bootstrap 5, with flexbox

https://codepen.io/spacemonki87/pen/VwbvogM

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="row" style="max-width: 1220px;">
            <div class="content text-center">
                <div class="value-prop text-center">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
                    <hr class="my-4">
                    <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
                </div>
                <div class="hero-row d-flex">
                    <div class="hero-img-container d-flex text-center align-items-center" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 84%;">
                        <img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="../img/hp_hero_note@2x__en.png" height="800" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-container d-flex align-items-center" style="width: 16%; min-width: 240px;">
                        <div class="hero-carousel-texts slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted">
                            <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
                                <div class="slick-track">
                                    <div class="hero-carousel-text slick-slide slick-cloned">
                                        <div class="heading">
                                            <p class="p-title hero-carousel-text-heading">FIND THINGS FAST</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="description">
                                            <p class="p-small">Get what you need, when you need it. Search gives you results as you type.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hero-carousel-text slick-slide slick-cloned">
                                        <div class="heading">
                                            <p class="p-title hero-carousel-text-heading">FIND THINGS FAST</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="description">
                                            <p class="p-small">Get what you need, when you need it. Search gives you results as you type.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hero-carousel-text slick-slide slick-cloned">
                                        <div class="heading">
                                            <p class="p-title hero-carousel-text-heading">FIND THINGS FAST</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="description">
                                            <p class="p-small">Get what you need, when you need it. Search gives you results as you type.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hero-carousel-text slick-slide slick-cloned">
                                        <div class="heading">
                                            <p class="p-title hero-carousel-text-heading">FIND THINGS FAST</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="description">
                                            <p class="p-small">Get what you need, when you need it. Search gives you results as you type.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hero-carousel-text slick-slide slick-cloned">
                                        <div class="heading">
                                            <p class="p-title hero-carousel-text-heading">FIND THINGS FAST</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="description">
                                            <p class="p-small">Get what you need, when you need it. Search gives you results as you type.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hero-carousel-text slick-slide slick-cloned">
                                        <div class="heading">
                                            <p class="p-title hero-carousel-text-heading">FIND THINGS FAST</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="description">
                                            <p class="p-small">Get what you need, when you need it. Search gives you results as you type.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any tips on mastering layouts is greatly appreciated

Comment: what is class `hero`?

Comment: Also, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Not to mention, it is usually not recommended to use `px`. Why have you not used percentage (which I am guessing from the px value should be 100)?

Comment: Consider awarding the bounty to the answer you have accepted.

Comment: the accepted answer will get auto-awarded the bounty points anyway once the period ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `mx-auto` class to first child of `div.hero`. This will set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, centering the contents of the page.

```html
<section>
    <div class="hero">
       <div class="row mx-auto" style="max-width: 1220px;">
...
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple in the end but i was pulling my hair out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this style into .hero

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: The OP is using BootStrap. Why not `class="d-flex flex-row"`?

Comment: ah yes we can use class instead. I have just suggested my idea :D